# Debian: keep custom changes in initscript

Tags: debian, apt

I had to modify the initscript for Postfix `/etc/init.d/postfix` to customize it for my special needs. Now I want to ensure, that in case of the `postfix` package being updated in the future (I am running Debian Wheezy Stable, but there could still be a security update) my modified initscript will not be overwritten. As I understand, packages ask before overwriting `config` files, but not initscripts.

What is the recommended way to do it (cleanly) ?

Comment: What was the modification you made?

Comment: Why is this relevant ?

Comment: Different changes go into different places, I wanted to understand what you changed first before taking the time to write up multiple methods that might not pertain to your particular changes.

Comment: OK, I am using SSL certificate which is stored on an encrypted disk. My modifications in `/etc/init.d/postfix` make sure that the encrypted disk is mounted before postfix starts. Also, the same encrypted disk is used as home for storing user `maildirs`. If `postfix` did not check before start, received mails could not be saved to `/home/<user>/mail/` and would be forever lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for `dpkg-divert`.

From the docs: [11.8 How do I override a file installed by a package, so that a different version can be used instead?](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-customizing.en.html).

*excerpt from docs*

> Suppose a sysadmin or local user wishes to use a program "login-local" rather than the program "login" provided by the Debian login package.
>
> Do not:
>
> Overwrite `/bin/login` with `login-local`.
>
> The package management system will not know about this change, and will simply overwrite your custom `/bin/login` whenever `login` (or any package that provides `/bin/login`) is installed or updated.
>
> Rather, do
>
> Execute:
>
> ```
>    $ sudo dpkg-divert --divert /bin/login.debian /bin/login
> ```
>
> in order to cause all future installations of the Debian `login` package to write the file `/bin/login` to `/bin/login.debian` instead.
>
> Then execute:
>
> ```
>    $ sudo cp login-local /bin/login
> ```
>
> to move your own locally-built program into place.
>
> Run `dpkg-divert --list` to see which diversions are currently active on your system.
>
> Details are given in the manual page `dpkg-divert(8)`.

I would determine what package the original Postfix init script was apart of, and divert just this one file with your modified version.

Answer (score 5):

All files under `/etc` are classified as “conffiles” (by Debian policy, it's specified in the package, not built in to dpkg). Dpkg prompts whether to overwrites each changed conffile on upgrade. Init scripts are no exception.

If you don't want to get prompted, or if you need this on a file in a package that isn't a conffile, you can use a [diversion](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html).

```
dpkg-divert --add --local --rename --divert /etc/init/postfix.debian /etc/init/postfix
```